# Terrain Rotation from MAC to Windows not retained

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a terrain that I have built for an island in Unity on MAC. I have recently been interested in developing the game on my windows machine because visual studio is better in this enviornment. In order to do so I created a git repository and used the standard .gitignore. Now I have it where it will load into windows but my problem is that the terrain appears to be rotated 90 degrees. The buildings, character and environment are all still placed correctly. The terrain also did not retain the paint that I applied to it with textures made available to me.

Below is a picture of how it looks in Unity on my Mac.

[image: Mac Build Correct]

Here is what it looks like in windows.

[image: Windows Build Wrong]

Any help would be very much appreciated

Thank you for your help in advance.

I have googled as much as I could but to no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded from Unity 2018.1.18f1 to 2019.1.1f1 and it created a couple of legitimate build errors that were resolved by going to:

**Edit** -> **Project Settings** -> **Player** -> **Other Settings** -> **Configuration** -> **Scripting Runtime Version*** and selecting **.NET 4.x Equivalent**

Essentially this was simply an issue of differing versions of Unity on MAC and Windows. All of the above issues have been resolved with the update and small configuration change.